# Di Perna-Lions theory for transport equations with an additional integral operator

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations

I'm looking for a reference about some possible generalization of the well-known Di Perna-Lions theory for transport equations (say, on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d$) of the form

\begin{align}
\partial_t u + b \cdot \nabla_x u+ c u=\Gamma(u).
\end{align}
Here, $b=b(t,x)$, $c=c(t,x)$ (with $(t,x) \in [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d$) are given and may be nonsmooth but with integrability properties for $c$ and Sobolev regularity for $b$, and $\Gamma$ is an integral operator of the form
\begin{align}
\Gamma(u)(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} K(x,x^*)u(t,x^*) \, \mathrm{d}x^*,
\end{align}
where $K$ is smooth and given.

When $\Gamma \equiv 0$, the well-posedness theory for that type of equation is by now well-known with the theory of renormalized solutions which enjoy nice properties of strong stability.

I was wondering if something in this direction is known when we add this type of integral operator in the righ-hand side.

Any help or reference is welcome !

Comment: Also on math.se : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4160120/transport-equation-with-an-additional-integral-operator-di-perna-lions-theory

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the post on Math.se to avoid repetitions

Comment: At the risk of sounding maybe naive: Isn't well-posedness of non-autonomous linear evolution equations respected by perturbations with bounded linear operators (due to a typical iteration argument)?